# What is the best way to @Conditional on the inclusion of the actuator feature?

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to make some of our auto configurations classes conditional on the presence of the SpringBoot actuator feature on the classpath.

Against which class should I write my @ConditionalOnClass annotation? Possible candidates are:

- `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration`
- `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndPoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, which one you choose, as long as it is packaged in the actuator JAR (which is the case for both of the classes you mentioned).

Comment: True. I was more looking for a class that is guaranteed to be in the jar whatever refactoring or changes that may occur in futur releases.

Comment: There is no guarantee.